# MySQL, LOAD DATA CONCURRENT LOCAL, disable & enable keys

Tags: mysql, concurrency, indexing, load-data-infile

I currently insert data into tables with **MyISAM** engine,

I wish to optimize `LOAD DATA` by building the indexes after LOAD DATA finishes (*disabling keys beforehand and enabling them after it finishes*).

From `LOAD DATA CONCURRENT` documentation, load data should add records to the end of the table, in the same time i am interested that a concurrent read to the same table will continue to use keys. I guaranty that the read operation will try to read info from the table only till 
the last available index (auto incremented id) before `LOAD DATA CONCURRENT` starts.

e.g.

`LOAD DATA CONCURRENT` will add data starting from index 100000 and will auto increment the index till 200000.

in the same time `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id <=99999 AND ...` statement may occur.

Is it possible to disable keys locally only for the `LOAD DATA CONCURRENT` statement, so that the read operation will still use the defined indexes in its `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that 1. your `id` column is the primary key, and that 2. you are planning to use `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS`.

According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html):

> ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS tells MySQL to stop updating nonunique indexes. (...) While the nonunique indexes are disabled, they are ignored for statements such as SELECT and EXPLAIN that otherwise would use them.

Therefore, the primary key will still be used for queries of the form

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id <=99999
```

However, it is not possible to disable keys on a subset of a table only.

Comment: +1, All my keys are just keys, i don't have any primary key (they are only indexes), will they be also used for the selects? and how to check for this to be sure?

Comment: @Michael Hum, a table should always have a primary key. If the indexes are non unique (neither a `PRIMARY KEY` nor a `UNIQUE` index, but a plain INDEX), then they will be disabled for good.

Comment: OK, than i see that there is no other way, this is also an answer. BTW, saying that table should always have a primary key is wrong!, there are reasons not to have a primary key as in case of range partitioning, and more other reasons...